# Combining ECC And RSA for a Web Based Chat system

Tags: rsa, aes, elliptic-curves, protocol-design

I'm a building a Web application chat message system(Over TLS) and i would like to know if the following theory is correct.

Sender

1. I'm generating keyPairs using **RSA** and another KeyPairs using **ECC**.
2. By using ECDH, I get $1$ shared Key from the ECC keyPairs.
3. Using the Shared Key $i$ encrypt the chat message using AES-256
4. I generate one random $256$-bit key
5. I encrypt AGAIN the encrypted message using the plainText of the key generated in 4)
6. I encrypt the key generated in 4) using RSA
7. I sent the encrypted chat message(5) along with the encrypted key(6) over socket

Receiver

1. Decrypts the encrypted key using RSA
2. Uses that key, and decrypts the chat message text
3. Decrypts the chat message text again, using the shared key from ECDH

I'm also providing an optional method to use a symmetric key to encrypt the Public RSA/ECC keys.

Is the above approach a good and secure way to build this system? What would you change?

Kind Regards

Comment: TLS provides plenty of security and I wouldn't worry about adding anything on top of it.

Comment: There's so many things that can go wrong, especially with implementing or using RSA, that I would not advise using this protocol outside a toy project. Just stick to TLS 1.3 and you'll be fine.